# Generate EF migrations from the difference between model and current database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I tried to apply code first migrations to my scenario, but it seems that the rational behind migrations is not compatible with mine.

consider this scenario:
I have an application and several users. I'm in version 1. I add a few features to my model for version 1.1, but some of my users will not upgrade. Now I add other features for version 1.2 and some people will upgrade from 1, others from 1.1. I need all of them to seamlessly upgrade their databases. I.E. the upgrade be calculated at runtime, from the difference between the current model and the current database, not at development time from the current model and last migration.

Am I getting something wrong? Is this scenario supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This scenario is supported for example if you have a database which maps to the version 1 model and you issue the

```
Update-Database
```

command from the Package Manager Console or use the following code:

```
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
dbMigrator.Update();
```

The database will be updated to the latest version by running all of the pending migration steps.

Of course this requires that between version 1 and version 1.1 you create a migration step then when you change your model to version two you create another migration step that migrates from version 1.1 to version 2.